# How do I secure my VPS server since I am using WIFI to access it?

Tags: ssh, iptables, wifi

Can i use SSH and IP tables to secure my server, even when i use wireless to access my server? My IP address appears to be dynamic each time i connect via wireless. What would be my options, and what would i need to look out for?

Comment: Given that properly securing a server has infinitesimal amounts to do with the IP address you're coming from, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Do you know of a resource that would guide me on setting up SSH keys for my Laptop?

Comment: `man ssh-keygen`

Answer (score 3):

Trying to secure a server you administer over the public internet by limiting which IPs can be used to administer it is a good way to lock yourself out.  I wouldn't recommend it.  Additionally, the technology you use to connect to the internet doesn't really matter at all in this case (you do know about the OSI model, I trust?).

One doesn't really use SSH to secure a server.  It's just a more secure way of accessing it than telnet, with the added ability to create tunnels as needed.

Really?  You would be much better served by setting a strong password, using client SSH keys, and not setting an IP ACL.

Comment: No I was not aware of the OSI model.  How can that be used in securing a VPS server?

Comment: To be blunt, it is a basic concept in networking (modularity of layers).  It means, among many, many other things, that your local access method is not important beyond your LAN.  If you are in the business of securing servers, it's something you should definitely be familiar with...